# Spresense SDK：デバックコンソールでデバックしながらシリアル通信できますか？

Tags: spresense

仕様をみるとメインと拡張ボードにそれぞれUSBシリアルがあるようですが、片方でデバックコンソールをひらき、Nuttxで動作する自作プログラムからもう一方のUARTを使うことは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

拡張ボードに出ている UART2 端子は、デバッグコンソールとは別の端子なので可能ですよ。
UART2 のデバイスファイルは、"/dev/ttyS2" になっているようです。

デバイスファイルを open して read, write が可能です

```c
fd = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR);
read(fd, buffer, size);
write(fd, buffer, size);
```

追記：
UART2のTx/Rxピンのことではなく、拡張ボード側のUSB端子を使ってシリアル通信する方法ですかね。USB CDC/ACMクラスが使えるようになっていて、以下が参考になると思います。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_system_cdcacm

Comment: ありがとうございます。本日実物をさわれたので`/dev/ttyS2`があるのを`Nuttx`から確認しました。ただホストPC側にシリアルデバイスが一つしか現れません。ホストはMacOS 10.15.5です。

Comment: UART2のTX,RX端子からUSB-UART変換器をかましてMacOSに接続しているってことですかね。シリアルデバイスが現れないのはUSB-UART変換モジュールのドライバとかの問題ではないでしょうか？

Comment: あ¨、拡張ボードのUSB端子をシリアルとして使いたいという意味ですかね、その方法を回答に追記してみました。

Comment: USB CDC/ACMの有効化でmacOS上に`/dev/cu.usbmodem0`ができて無事シリアルの通信ができました！ありがとうございました。